# Sinch verification not working with UK number

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

I have implemented `SinchVerification`, here is my code

```
Config config = SinchVerification.config().applicationKey(getResources().getString(R.string.sinch_app_key)).context(getApplicationContext()).build();
final Verification verification = SinchVerification.createSmsVerification(config, phone, listener);
verification.initiate();
```

It is working for India and US but somehow it is not working with UK, It is calling `onVerificationFailed(Exception e)` method with following logcat.

phone number is something like +44**********

```
com.sinch.verification.CodeInterceptionException: Did not receive sms.
at com.sinch.verification.internal.sms.SmsInterceptor.onError(SmsInterceptor.java:135)
at com.sinch.verification.internal.sms.SmsInterceptor.access$100(SmsInterceptor.java:19)
at com.sinch.verification.internal.sms.SmsInterceptor$1.run(SmsInterceptor.java:78)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I have also checked with official doc of sinch for available operators with country, my operator is `Telefonica O2 UK` and it is supported by `sinch`.

Comment: Hi, good news nothing wrong with your code, can you please mail in to support@sinch.com with the number you have problem with since its likely an issue with that number only.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exception. What you need to do is:

1. Go to your Sinch Developers Account Dashboard
2. Apps => SMS => Activate SMS
3. You will receive an email. Reply to that email with the asked details and they will activate that for you.
4. You are Done!